# Notepad++ remove line by duplicate word

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a problem removing some lines with same word. I`ve tried lots of reg exp but none works. Example:

```
B005XJ4PXG  667
B00008W5TT  1111
B005XIF874  919
B00008W5TT  1305
B00008W5TT  1350
B0000B31MK  918
B0000B31MK  1340
```

My text doc is large so i have many different duplicate words. What i need is to remove the duplicates and leave the line with the highest value on the right side.

Example:

```
B0000B31MK  918
B0000B31MK  1340
```

Remove B0000B31MK   918 line.

Comment: That is not a job for regex, a single regex can't select highest value. You should write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: *and leave the line with the highest value on the right side* - you can not compare numbers with regex

Comment: what about removing the duplicates ? ... ignore the highest value thing. What i`ve tried, still leaves duplicates.

Comment: @PatruOre Which programming language are you familiar with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small perl script that does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %uniq;
# open input file
open my $fh_in, '<', 'input_file.txt' or die $!;
# read the file line by line until the end of file
while(<$fh_in>){
    # remove line break
    chomp;
    # split on space
    my ($word, $val) = split;
    # populate the hash, key is the word, the bigest value will be kept at the end
    $uniq{$word} = $val if !exists $uniq{$word} or $uniq{$word} < $val;
}
# open output file
open my $fh_out, '>', 'output_file.txt' or die $!;
# foreach word, value pair
while(my($w,$v)=each%uniq) {
    # print the pair in the output file
    print $fh_out "$w\t$v\n";
}
```

**Usage:**

**input_file.txt**

```
B005XJ4PXG  667
B00008W5TT  1111
B005XIF874  919
B00008W5TT  1305
B00008W5TT  1350
B0000B31MK  918
B0000B31MK  1340
```

**run script:**

```
$perl test.pl
```

**output_file.txt:**

```
B00008W5TT  1350
B0000B31MK  1340
B005XIF874  919
B005XJ4PXG  667
```

Comment: Thanks. I`ll give it a try later.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you are on Windows. If you can install Pandas with this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4v9_K3Rq3Y), you can do it in few lines like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('fullpath_of_oldfile', sep='\s+',
                                  header=None).groupby([0]).last().reset_index()
df.to_csv('fullpath_of_newfile', header=None, columns=None)
```

Comment: Thanks. I`ll give it a try later.